# jQuery animate scrolldown to div by <a href""> From 1 html to another html site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'am on my way to make a site for my friend who is a massage therapist.

And I have a boostrap dropboxmenu with treatment-links to the treatment.html on the index.html.

How do I create multiple links that with jQuery make it scroll down to the specific treatment on the new treatment.html when having multiple treatments?

Sorry for bad english. Trying my best.
I'am very very novice to javascript and jquery - first time actually..

I found this code, but it don't work?

```
<!-- Treatment scrolldown -->
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#treatment1').offset().top }, 1000);

$("html, body").delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: $('#treatment1').offset().top }, 2000);
<!-- End Treatment scrolldown -->
```

Comment: Where do you have this code? Is it wrapped in a jQuery ready function? Have you included jQuery? Any console errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
<body id="body">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="treatment1.html" data-section="section1" class="menu-button">Treatment1 section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="treatment1.html" data-section="section2" class="menu-button">Treatment1 section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="treatment2.html" data-section="section1" class="menu-button">Treatment2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        $(function () {

            $(".menu-button").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                var section = $(this).data("section");

                $("#body").load(href, function () {
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + section).offset().top }, 1000);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Make sure you have jQuery included, and before the script.

Comment: Read the question again. He doesn't want to scroll down on the current page. He wants to load a new html document that scrolls down based on the link that was used to open that html document.

Comment: Much better :) Although technically this will load the new page inside the current one instead of opening it, I fully agree that this is probably the only viable solution. Nicely done :)

Comment: Thanks alot! I will play around with it this afternoon and will pm you if I have some problems! :-D

Answer (score 0):

first: you cant use html-comments inside js

second you need to wrap the ode by a script tag

third you have to run this in a self-executing function e.g at document ready event

fourth you need to include jquery before your script block

so sth like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#treatment1').offset().top }, 1000);

    $("html, body").delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: $('#treatment1').offset().top }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

and fifth: you should definatly check the browser console which will outup the errors you have